# Android httppsot for insert into mysql database,,,

Tags: php, android, mysql

I can be able to select the data from the mysql database,,,,I have tried the same mathodology to insert into mysql database ,,but its not working,,,, 
Suggestion plz ,,,Thanks in advance

```
package com.example.inserttbl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;



import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Inserttbl extends Activity {
private static Button signup;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inserttbl);
        signup=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new insert_DB().execute();

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.inserttbl, menu);
        return true;
    }

   private class insert_DB extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
   {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.3:81/arun/Schoolapp.php");   
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  

        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parentname","arun"));  
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("childname","arun1"));  
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("childid","1234"));  
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","arun_android"));  
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password","sachin"));  
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email","arunshankar@gmail.com"));  
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender","male"));  
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobileno","9840992982"));  

        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs,HTTP.UTF_8);  
        post.setEntity(entity);  
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);  
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
   } 
}
```

My php code Schoolapp.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","arun","sachin11");

$new_db="CREATE DATABASE Schoolapp";

$select_db=mysqli_select_db($con,"Schoolapp");

$create_tbl = "CREATE TABLE SchoolDB(ParentName CHAR(30),ChildPassportName CHAR(30),ChildID INT,Username CHAR(30),Password CHAR(30),Email varchar(50),Gender CHAR(30),MobileNo INT )";

$parentname = $_POST['parentname'];
$childname = $_POST['childname'];
$childid = $_POST['childid'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$mobileno = $_POST['mobileno'];

$register="INSERT INTO SchoolDB (ParentName, ChildPassportName, ChildID,Username,Password,Email,Gender,MobileNo)
            VALUES ('$parentname','$childname','$childid','$username','$password','$email','$gender','$mobileno')";
if (mysqli_query($con,$register))
  {
  echo "value inserted";
  }
else
  {
  echo "not inserted " . mysqli_error($con);
  }

mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: What is the problem, are you getting any error or what?

Comment: Sorry man,,its working ,,,wrong filename

Comment: Can I code this without Asynctask,,,will it work

Comment: Yes it will work, but using asynctask is best practise, or may be sometime you will get error of threading.

Comment: One small error ,,,dont know why ,,, in the above code i have inserted mobile no as 9840992982 ,,but in my database it inserted as 2147483647,,, no idea