# Android HTTP post method for php mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I want to request json data using HTTP post method,,,,How can i do it,,,,
I have tried something using JSON parser ,but it not works ,,,,
Can you help me with the code,,thanks in advance

My php file

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","arun","sachin11");
$rows = array();
$db_select = mysql_select_db('Schoolapp', $con);
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ChildPassportName,ChildID FROM SchoolDB where Username='$username' and Password='$password'",$con);
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

My php output:

```
[{"ChildPassportName":"arun2","ChildID":"111"}]
```

MyJava file

```
package com.example.childprofile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ChildProfile extends Activity {
    private TextView childname,childid;

    private Button get;
    private EditText username,password;
    private JSONObject jObj;
    private static String user,pass,json;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.child_profile);
        username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.profile_username);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.profile_password);
        childname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_email);
        childid=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_childid);
        get=(Button) findViewById(R.id.profile_button1);
        get.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new sendPostData().execute();
            }
        });
    }
    private class sendPostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
            @Override
        protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {  


                    user=username.getText().toString();
                    pass=password.getText().toString();
                    String link="http://192.168.1.22:81/arun.php?";
                    String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") 
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8");
                    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") 
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");
                    URL url = new URL(link);
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); 
                    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter
                    (conn.getOutputStream()); 
                    wr.write( data ); 
                    wr.flush(); 
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())); 
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    // Read Server Response
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                       sb.append(line);
                       break;
                    }
                    json=sb.toString();

                   return json;

        }
           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               //View your result here.
                  jObj = new JSONObject(result);
                  childname.settext(jObj.getstring["ChildPassportName"]);
                  childid.settext(jObj.getstring["ChildID"]);
               }
     }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about "but it not works"?

Comment: I have included my Java code above,,

Comment: `http://192.168.1.22:81/arun/.php` ??? is this how you call a .php url ? There should be a valid .php file name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android httppsot for insert into mysql database,,,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988009/android-httppsot-for-insert-into-mysql-database)

Comment: @ArunShankar, you are calling a file name `.php` which I guess is incorrect.

Comment: "http://192.168.1.22:81/arun.php?" ,,this name only am calling

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
 jObj = new JSONObject(result);
                  childname.settext(jObj.getstring["ChildPassportName"]);
                  childid.settext(jObj.getstring["ChildID"]);
               }

This lines oly shows errors

Answer (score 0):

This would be an example on how to wait for the response from the server side, I've tried to comment the relevant parts so it should be easy to understand.

```
HttpResponse response = null;

try {
  // Fill in the POST pair you want to sent to the server
  final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mykey", "myvalue"));
  httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

  // Send the request
  response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
}
catch (final ClientProtocolException e) { ... }
catch (final IOException e) { ... }

// Now you have to process the response    
InputStream ips;
try {
  ips = response.getEntity().getContent();
  final BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips, "UTF-8"));

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String s;
  while (true) {
    s = buf.readLine();
    if ((s == null) || (s.length() == 0))
      break;
    sb.append(s);
  }

  buf.close();
  ips.close();

  Log.d("JSONResponse", "My response from the server is: " + sb.toString());
} 
catch (IllegalStateException e1) { } 
catch (IOException e1) { }

if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
  try { throw new Exception(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase()); } 
  catch (final Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This should probably give you the right JSON using HTTP POST
<?php
    $json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cat_name = $data->lang;
    $cat_name="Components";
    $cat_name= trim(ucfirst($cat_name));
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","arun","sachin11");
    $rows = array();
    $db_select = mysql_select_db('Schoolapp', $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT
```

ChildPassportName,ChildID 
                  FROM SchoolDB 
                  where Username='$username' 
                  and Password='$password'",$con);
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            $rows[] = $r;
        }
        print json_encode($rows);

```
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```